# Estimating Probabilities in Perudo

Tags: r, probability, dice

I am new to coding and using R. I am working on a project to simulate the game Liar's Dice, also known as Perudo, and have some questions about creating the simulation.

Basically, the game consists of two or more players rolling five dice in a cup, turning it over, and and making bids on how many of a certain side they think is on the table. You can look at your own dice, but not anyone else's. To make bids, on your turn you would say "two 5's," which would mean there are at least two dice that landed on 5. Each bid will either increase the side or the amount. So if you said "two 5's," I could then say "two 6's" or "three 3's" on my turn.

When you believe the last bid is incorrect, you would say "Liar" on your turn, then everyone reveals their dice. If you were wrong, you lose a dice, but if you were right, the last bidder loses a dice. This continues until there is only one player left who has dice.

First, I decided to create a function called cup() which rolls a cup of five six-sided dice.

```
cup <- function(sides = 6, dice = 5){
  sample(1:sides, size = dice, replace = TRUE)
}
```

Next, with a little assistance, I created a new function called cups() which rolls three cups for three players.

```
cups <- function(players = 3, sides = 6, dice = 5){
  out <- cup(sides, dice)
  for(i in 2:players){
    out <- rbind(out, cup(sides, dice))
  }
  rownames(out) <- 1:players
  rownames(out) <- c("P1", "P2", "P3")
  return(out)
}
```

What I want to accomplish next is to create a table of probabilities of possible dice outcomes. In other words, what's the probability of there being at least two of a side given fifteen dice (five for each player) in play? And then the probability of there being three, four, five, etc. all the way up to fifteen in this case.

My question is how would I go about doing this in R? And what direction should I go in after getting the probabilities in R?

Comment: I think you will find that with such a broad and unspecific question you will not get an answer. I suggest you break down the problem into specific questions that are easier to address.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an empirical process for determining the percentage outcomes of all the same, 4 the same, 3 the same, 2 the same, none the same upon rolling 5 die:

```
library(gtools) # package with permutations function
allcombos <- permutations(6, 5, repeats.allowed = TRUE) # all 6 choose 5 with replacment combos
alluniques <- apply(allcombos, 1, unique) # uniques for each combo
alllengths <- sapply(alluniques, length) # lengths for each combo imputes num repeats
alllengths2 <- as.factor(alllengths) # convert to factor to count unique
allsum <- summary(alllengths2) # sum by num uniques
allsum
1    2    3    4    5  # 1=all same, 2=4 same, 3=3 same, 4=2 same, 5=all different
6  450 3000 3600  720 
totsum <- sum(allsum)
allfrac <- allsum / totsum
allpercent <- allfrac * 100
allpercent
1           2           3           4           5 
0.07716049  5.78703704 38.58024691 46.29629630  9.25925926 # percentage breakout
```

There is no doubt an analytical solution but I don't know what it is.  You could use standard probability calculations to estimate specific outcomes among multiple players.  E.g. P(at least 1 4-same | 3 players) or run some simulations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's likely more than you asked for but focusing on number of sides on the dice, total number of dice and probability of rolling `Nrolled` or more

```r
dicegame <- function(Nsides = 6,
                     Ndice = 5,
                     Nrolled = 1,
                     verbose = FALSE)
{
   total_possible_outcomes <- choose(Nsides + Ndice - 1, Ndice)

   outcomes_matrix <- t(combn(Nsides + Ndice - 1,
                              Ndice,
                              sort)) - matrix(rep(c(0:(Ndice - 1)),
                                                  each = total_possible_outcomes),
                                              nrow = total_possible_outcomes)

   chances <- sum(apply(outcomes_matrix, 1,  function(x) sum(x==2)) >= Nrolled) / total_possible_outcomes

   if(verbose) {
      cat(paste("Number of dice", 
                Ndice,
                "each with", Nsides, "sides",
                "chances of rolling", Nrolled, 
                "\n or more of any one side are:\n"))
   }
   return(chances)
#   return(total_possible_outcomes)
#   return(outcomes_matrix)
}

dicegame(verbose = TRUE)
#> Number of dice 5 each with 6 sides chances of rolling 1 
#>  or more of any one side are:
#> [1] 0.5

dicegame(6, 15, 10)
#> [1] 0.01625387
```

Answer (score -1):

Using probability we can demonstrate that the probability to get a value n times is equal to :
[image]

we can easily write this into an R function:

```r
prob_get_n <- function(ntimes, players=3, dice=5, sides=6){
    if(missing(ntimes)) ntimes <- 0:(players*dice)
    choose(players*dice,ntimes)*(1-1/sides)^((players*dice)-ntimes)*sides^(-ntimes)
}
```

Notice that this function is by construction vectorised ie it accepts `1:2`, `c(9,5)` as valid inputs.

```r
prob_get_n() -> probs
data.frame(ntimes=1:length(probs)-1, probs=probs,or_more= rev(cumsum(rev(probs))))
   ntimes        probs      or_more
1       0 6.490547e-02 1.000000e+00
2       1 1.947164e-01 9.350945e-01
3       2 2.726030e-01 7.403781e-01
4       3 2.362559e-01 4.677751e-01
5       4 1.417535e-01 2.315192e-01
6       5 6.237156e-02 8.976567e-02
7       6 2.079052e-02 2.739411e-02
8       7 5.346134e-03 6.603585e-03
9       8 1.069227e-03 1.257451e-03
10      9 1.663242e-04 1.882242e-04
11     10 1.995890e-05 2.190005e-05
12     11 1.814445e-06 1.941153e-06
13     12 1.209630e-07 1.267076e-07
14     13 5.582909e-09 5.744548e-09
15     14 1.595117e-10 1.616385e-10
16     15 2.126822e-12 2.126822e-12
```

## Edit

Or we can use R built in `dbinom` function to get the distribution and `pbinom` to get the cumulative probability function:

```r
probs <- function(ntimes, players=3, dice=5, sides=6){
    if(missing(ntimes)) ntimes <- 0:(players*dice)
    data.frame(ntimes=ntimes, probs=dbinom(ntimes, players*dice, 1/sides), or_more=1-pbinom(ntimes-1, players*dice, 1/sides))
}
   ntimes        probs      or_more
1       0 6.490547e-02 1.000000e+00
2       1 1.947164e-01 9.350945e-01
3       2 2.726030e-01 7.403781e-01
4       3 2.362559e-01 4.677751e-01
5       4 1.417535e-01 2.315192e-01
6       5 6.237156e-02 8.976567e-02
7       6 2.079052e-02 2.739411e-02
8       7 5.346134e-03 6.603585e-03
9       8 1.069227e-03 1.257451e-03
10      9 1.663242e-04 1.882242e-04
11     10 1.995890e-05 2.190005e-05
12     11 1.814445e-06 1.941153e-06
13     12 1.209630e-07 1.267076e-07
14     13 5.582909e-09 5.744548e-09
15     14 1.595117e-10 1.616385e-10
16     15 2.126822e-12 2.126743e-12
```

Comment: Not to be argumentative but your algorithm is off.  Take the simplest case. 1 player, 2 dice with 6 sides.  OP wants to know what the probability is of rolling two (or more) sixes.  There are exactly 21 unique ways the two dice can roll we can make a matrix of all 21 possibilities with `t(combn(6 + 2 - 1, 2, sort)) - matrix(rep(c(0:(2 - 1)), each = choose(6 + 2 - 1, 2)), nrow = choose(6 + 2 - 1, 2))` .  Of the 21 rows only 1 matches two sixes.  So the probability is 1/21 = 0.04761905 which is what my code renders.  Your `probs(2, 1, 2, 6)` gives `0.02777778 0.02777778` which is incorrect.

Comment: FWIW I considered adding a `players` parameter but OP stated that players "lose" dice as the game progresses so any function would have to account for the fact that different players could have different numbers of dice which is why I stuck to the total number of dice being rolled.

Comment: @ChuckP in your comment you're not checking all the combinations that's why you're getting faulty results we have 36 combinations and only one of them is two sixes => 1/36 = .027777778. You're not accounting for order

Comment: Neither order nor player matter in the game.  It's simply the count.  Whether it's a 6 & 1 or 1 & 6 there is still only one showing.